# History/blame git submodule

Tags: git

I have a project `A` that uses project `B` as a git submodule:

```
A
└── B
```

I want to find which commit in `A` updated the current ref for `B`. The `A/.gitmodules` file only contains the remote, not the ref. And running this does not work:

```
git blame -- B
```

> ```
> fatal: no such path 'B' in HEAD
> ```

How can I find the commit in `A` that changed which commit of `B` to check out?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can see the history using `git log`:

```
git log -- B
```

> ```
> commit 469e844f71d60f862e14e64302dbc849cbc7ba51
> ```

Or to see a summary of all the changed commits:

```
git log --patch-with-stat -- B | grep commit
```

> ```
> commit 469e844f71d60f862e14e64302dbc849cbc7ba51
> -Subproject commit a677c5ccb01071c6cfe5a6de9bddcd43ad5198ca
> +Subproject commit 02ec5cb265a744f0a8a710920f0e2a832cc433f2
> ```

The first line is the commit in project `A`, while the other lines show how project `B` has changed.